# Camera Aligned To Sphere Surface

Tags: camera, rotation, planet, sphere

I am writing a planet renderer and have come across a problem that is really limiting the usability of the program. When I am on the planet (anywhere but the north pole) I cannot rotate the camera to the left or to the right as I would if I was on a flat plane. Instead I can only move as if I were aligned to a regular flat plane. This gives me awkward viewing as seen here: [image]

This limits me to only really looking straight ahead of the camera and straight behind the camera.

I drew this to try to illustrate the problem: 
[image]

Will setting the up-vector of the camera to be the the point on the sphere where I am located normalized alleviate this problem? 
I am at a dead-end here and any ideas would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: One possibility to look at is rotating the planet instead of the camera. This would make things like physics and movement a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an up vector, and a "look" vector (forward), you can compute a *lookat* matrix. Glu (not used much these days) has `gluLookAt`, which is replicated in math libraries [such as glm](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.2/api/a00245.html#ga2d6b6c381f047ea4d9ca4145fed9edd5). There's plenty material on it, if you do some searching.

Just a quick pseudo-code summary of a `lookat` function:

```
mat4x4 lookat(vec3 up, vec3 forward, vec3 translation)
    vec3 right = cross(forward, up)

    mat4x4 lookatMatrix;
    lookatMatrix[0] = right; // 0 = first collumn
    lookatMatrix[1] = up;
    lookatMatrix[2] = forward;

    // After that, multiply by the camera's translation matrix, and you're set
}
```

Right, up and forward are essentially the positive x, y and z axes for your camera.

As for getting the the "up" direction, as you suggested, the vector from the centre of the planet, to the camera, would work.

Comment: I believe `gluLookat` is deprecated.

Comment: Right, it is deprecated in core OpenGL, hence why it's been implemented in glm. It's still a good example of how the world to camera matrix can be computed, and there's plenty literature describing how it's achieved.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but as this took me longer than I wish to admit to get the behaviour I wanted, I decided to post it in case it helps someone.

From your image, your roll angle is undesirably not 0. We want to be able to change only the pitch/yaw of our camera as we move around, so we need to keep the camera's right vector always parallel to the ground.

Code:

```
// pitch is the desired pitch angle. You can calculate/clip it as you want

// yawOffset is the angle you want to rotate the yaw by. I calculate it using the amount of pixels the mouse moved in the horizontal since the last frame 

// GetPointRotatedAroundAxis(p, axis, angle) is a helper function that returns the point (p) rotated by the angle (angle) around the unit axis (axis). You can implement it with quaternions or standard 3d rotation matrices. I'll ommit for brevity

// projPointUAxis(p, uAxis) returns the projection of point (p) in unit axis (uAxis). It can be computed as uAxis * dot(p, uAxis)

// Do game logic, update position, etc.

// Get unit vector from sphere's center to camera's position
vec3 normal = normalize(pos - sphereCenter);

// "erase" component parallel to our normal that was generated if the camera moved since last frame, as we want to stay perpendicular to the ground where we are (in other others, right vector always parallel, in other words, roll == 0)
right -= projPointUAxis(right, normal);
// This normalization is mandatory. If right is the null vector (vec3(0, 0, 0,)), normalizing results in a division by 0, but you shouldn't need to worry about it, unless you can magically teleport 90 degrees in 1 frame to get to the position where right == normal
right = normalize(right);

// Update right vector according to new yawOffset
// Always good to normalize because of floating point errors
right = normalize(GetPointRotatedAroundAxis(right, normal, yawOffset));

// Get camera's up vector from pitch in range [-PI/2, PI/2] radians
up = normalize(GetPointRotatedAroundAxis(normal, right, pitch);

front = normalize(cross(up, right));
```

Here's what I got:
[image]